# Strange Last Error in P/Invoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke

guys! I am calling "PrintDlg" Win32 API via P/Invoke. Strange enough, if I use Visual Studio debug mode (press F5) to run my application, the last error is 122, which means "The data area passed to a system call is too small" , but if i ran it with Ctrl+F5, the last error is 0 and the  message is "The operation completed successfully". How could this be possible?  Many thanks...

Comment: dude, you have like 10 questions with multiple answers and none accepted. I think I will spend my time elsewhere......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Don't check for an error unless the function returns false.

b) Don't use GetLastError, use CommDlgExtendedError [as the docs suggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646940(VS.85).aspx).

c) Start accepting answers on your questions. :)

Comment: thanks Curt. sorry for the delayed marking action. thanks for reminding. :D